# What is this data structure called?

Tags: data-structures, circular-buffer

In my current project I'll need a data structure with the following properties:

- create with fixed size (for example 10)
- add elements. When the capacity is reached the first element will be overwritten, next the seconds element will be overwritten, and so on...

How is this called? I'm guessing circular-something...

Comment: doesn't the circular-buffer tag you used directly answer that?

Comment: @NathanHughes Haha, I was typing circular and just used something, which sounded familiar. Great :) Thanks.

Comment: Circular queue can be used

Comment: @Ticktick: thanks, updated tag info accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).